# xsd choice for multiple elements

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I would like my Xml file to look like the following

```xml
<root>
    <name>a</name>
    <age>23</age>
</root>
```

```
 or
```

```xml
<root>
    <empno>b<empno>
    <designation>ase</designation>
</root>
```

is it possible to create a XML schema for the above using a "choice" indicator?something like below.

```xml
<xsd:element name="root">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:choice>

<xsd:element name="name"/>
<xsd:element name="age" />
```

```
     or
```

```xml
<xsd:element name="empno"/>
<xsd:element name="designation" />

<xsd:choice>

</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element>
```

Is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, You are almost there.. just missing a `sequence` .. Since it's the set of fields you have to wrap them under sequence..

These sequence tags will be under `<Choice>` tag. Now either of these set of tags (Sequence) will be validated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="empno" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="designation" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**I would like to add one more suggestion here:**

I observe that you use nested declarations .. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="trunk">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="branch1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="branch2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="other" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Always prefer usage of Custom types! Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>

  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="trunk" type="trunk"/>
      <xs:element name="other" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="trunk">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="branch1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="branch2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This improves readability and you can reuse the complexType/simpleType ..

hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tried to parse one of simple xml file. Actually i expected to see only one of the option either first element or second element. But my dom parser reads both of them. Did I confuse the different terms?

Comment: if you want to see only one of the option then don't use `<sequence>` inside `<choice>` :)